# How can we get all user listing from Userpool & identity both (AWS Cognito)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I'm using AWS Cognito for user authentication.
The users who are logged in through Facebook/ google+ are listed in federated identity pool where as the users who are logged in through custom sign up process are listed in cognito user pool.
So, how can we manage both the list of users? Is there any way to access and manage both the list of users in a single application.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to have your User Pools pool configured as a provider for your identity pool. Once that's configured, those identities should automatically show up as identities inside the identity pool with user pools as a linked login, and will be included in the ListIdentities results. See [the Cognito developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) for specifics on how to link the two, if you are unsure of how to do so.

I'm unsure from your question if you are integrating them already, but if not, Cognito does not currently support a way to list both sets of users.